# Moving a WordPress site to Docker, and eventually to a server

Tags: wordpress, docker, localhost

I have been working on a WordPress website for my internship, and my superiors have requested that I try to containerize it to make future updates more convenient. They suggested that I use Docker.

Right now the site running on my local machine (Mac), and eventually I will have to migrate it to a company server to replace the current website. I have several questions regarding this.

- Is Docker the right tool for this task?
- What exactly does containerization contribute?
- Should I move the site to Docker before or after moving the site to the server?
- I've seen a lot of guides use Nginx. What exactly do I need this for?
- How should I go about updating the URLs?
- How should I go about replacing the preexisting site?

Any assistance or direction toward helpful resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. Is Docker the right tool for this task?

Yes. You have another option [rkt](https://coreos.com/rkt) from CoreOs team. But it is not as popular as Docker

### 2. What exactly does containerization contribute?

Containerization means, you are packaging the necessary software that needs to run your application along with the application. Your final artifact will no longer be a jar/war file, instead it will be a Docker image. The problem that containerization addresses is the classic problem "it works on my machine (I don't know about production)". In other words, it gives you immutable infrastructure (its better left it that way, don't change stuffs in container after ssh ing to it)

### 3. Should I move the site to Docker before or after moving the site to the server?

Before... You should start developing with Docker in place, then it will be easier for you. Remember, Docker is addressing one issue "It works on my machine"

### 4. I've seen a lot of guides use Nginx. What exactly do I need this for?

If you have a static site which involves only html css and javascript, you can use nginx to host your site. But if you have some dynamic contents in your website and you need a server side technology (like java nodejs, php, go or cgi.. well, you got the picture). Nginx can be used as front end proxy too.. This a whole different topic

### 5. How should I go about updating the URLs?

I hope you have a DNS system in your enterprise, if thats the case you can ask them to repoint it to your new IP (If you are planning to deploy it in a new server). Or just buy some downtime, bring down the old application and bring up the new shiny Dockerised app in the same machine and same port number..

### 6. How should I go about replacing the preexisting site?

It depends on your site, depends on what kind of Technology you uses.

- Is it a static website-- you can use nginx in Docker container
- Is it Java? You can use OpenJDK-Alpine (just my opinion) docker image
- ...
- And So on..

Answer (score 0):

**Updating the URLs**
A good practice is to have a `baseURL` defined in your code and just use `baseURL + "path"` in order to form other URLs. 
For example:

```js
baseURL = "https://example.com/"
blogURL = baseURL + "blog"
document.getElementById("old-url").innerHTML = blogURL
// now if you need to change your domain to .org instead of .com, you can just change baseURL to your new domain name

baseURL = "https://new-example.org/"
blogURL = baseURL + "blog"
document.getElementById("new-url").innerHTML = blogURL
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  OLD BLOG URL is:
  <div id="old-url"></div>
  <br>
  NEW BLOG URL is:
  <div id="new-url"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Replacing the preexisting site**

- Generally what happens is for testing a folder inside the root folder of existing website is created. This is done so that you can go to https://example.com to see the old site. And then go to https://example.com/new to see the new site.
- When all the testing is done, the contents of new folder are shifted to root folder and the contents of old website are generally shifted to a https://example.com/old path.